# How to modify the keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Title more or less says it all.  Specifically, I've become increasingly annoyed that in order to run an ant script I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>.  But I think If I had this power I would many things I would change the shortcuts for/add shortcuts for things that don't currently have them.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

*Window > Preferences > General > Keys*

In particular, edit the "Run Ant Build" command.

Comment: Useful shortcuts : `Ctrl + Shift + L` for the list of currently available shortcuts, and hit `Ctrl + Shift + L` again to show the shortcut preference window.

Comment: For the ones who use Sublime, overiding a shorctut `Ctrl + p` is a must

Comment: @krookedking comment is more useful. Check for conflicts when applying new shortcuts.`Ctrl+Shift+L` and again `Ctrl+Shift+L`

Answer (score 30):

For Windows:

*Window > Preferences > General > Keys*

Answer (score 21):

For mac that would be

*Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys*

Answer (score 15):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will open the current list of defined shortcuts, again pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will open preference page from where the shortcuts can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note make sure your newly mapped Shortcut won't have any conflicts on the right of the Keys window/menu.

If so choose a combination that will work; doesn't have any conflicts with existing ( default ) settings.

Hope this helps.