# Why are refactoring shortcuts in eclipse missing on mac os?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.1 on Mac Os.

In an earlier Version of Eclipse I hat a lot of nice refactoring shortcuts like:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> extract method
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> inline

Lately if I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>; I insert `µ` instead of extracting a method and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>; inserts `^`. The shortcuts are also not shown in the refactoring menu anymore.

Those missing shortcuts really slow me down. 
I think the shortcuts are not shown/active because the native Mac OS shortcuts take precedence.

How can I re enable those shortcuts?

**UPDATE**

I just installed Eclipse Indigo and the Shortcuts are missing again. I use them all the time and replacing code with `µ` all the time is very very annoying.

Has anybody encountered this problem as well?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a clean install of the 64bit version of Eclipse and the shortcuts reappeared.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can use the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut in any given editor to see a list of available keyboard shortcut... and a second <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will display a popup with all possible shortcuts in your Eclipse (can be filtered for "extract method" for example).

That would at least allow you to see the current shortcut for any given action.

Answer (score 2):

If you go in *Preferences...* -> *General* -> *Keys*, search for the description of the action that doesn't work in the list. Once selected, look whether there's a conflict (in the conflict list below). There's a chance there's a conflicting shortcut set up for another action (possibly by another plugin).

Once you've identified the other conflicting action, look for it in the list: you can then either unbind it completely or change it scope (in the *When* drop-down list) to restrict it to a particular plugin for example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Aptana plugin, or any other plugins? In my case I was able to bring shortcuts back by uninstalling Aptana.