# Searching references of a particular java class

Tags: java, eclipse

I  was searching for a shortcut in Eclipse which would show the references of the selected Java class elsewhere. Presently I right click on the Java class and select `References`.

It would be great if I could be told the shortcut for this.

Is there a guide which I could refer to, to find out the most-used Eclipse shortcuts ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all References of selected item in Workspace : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
To find all References of selected item in Current class : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

### Learning Eclipse Shortcuts

If you are starting out with Eclipse Shortcuts, I would suggest that it might not we worthwhile trying to learn them by just reading them.

#### Suggested strategy to remember shortcuts

Try this out :

1. Identify the one activity/action that you do most often.

   Examples :
    
   `Open Resource` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) which allows you to search for and open a file in the workspace. 

   `Switch Between Tabs` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> )
2. Once you have identified the oft-used activity above, **USE IT** as often as possible ( which shouldn't be difficult given the fact that we identified an oft-used action to start with)
3. Repeat :)

#### Tip - Shortcut groups

It might be useful to remember shortcut `Groups`. Many a time you'll find that they are intuitive and easily lend themselves to memorization.

**Example - The `Execute` Group of Shortcuts**

Eclipse has this concept of multi-key shortcuts (something that I had not come across before Eclipse) which require you to press a sequence of Characters ( such as Alt + Shift + X) and then another Character after it. This allows the '*grouping*' of related shortcuts.

For instance to Execute pretty much anything you first press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then another character depending upon what you are executing. Thus, one would use the following combinations :
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, J  : To execute the main method of a Java class
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, T  : To run a Junit Test (this would run a specific test or all the test in the class depending upon the position of the cursor when this shortcut is pressed)

The above are easy to remember as Alt + Shift + **X** ecute, a **J** ava class or a JUnit **T** est.

Now the beauty of this is, once you are used to the above shortcuts you change **X** ecute to **D** ebug and just like that you have two new shortcuts to Run a Java class or JUnit test in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Finding references in Eclipse is done by the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Just makes sure the mouse cursor is on the class and use the key combination. The same shortcut works for method or variables.