# Can I change the shortcut in Eclipse for indenting code?

Tags: eclipse

I know it's tab and shift-tab for right and left respectively, but I prefer Sublime Text 2's (and quite frankly, most IDEs/text editors) where it's ctrl-] and ctrl-[.

Any way to change this?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse).

Comment: I know, but there's no shortcut for indent listed under shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I have an English Keyboard but I am typing in French, so there are some missing keys. I made a windows script in [AutoIt3](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to send the characters `<` an `>` by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+,` and `CTRL+SHIFT.`. I made an example for your problem below:

Documentation: [WinTitleMatchMode](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm), [WinActive](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActive.htm)

```
; File CustomShortcutEclipse.au3

HotKeySet("^[","leftTabEclipse")
HotKeySet("^]","rightTabEclipse")
HotKeySet("{ESC}","escape")

AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

While(True)
  Sleep(1000)
WEnd

Func escape()
  Exit
EndFunc

Func leftTabEclipse()
  If WinActive("Eclise SDK") Then
    Send("{TAB}")
  EndIf
EndFunc

Func rightTabEclipse()
  If WinActive("Eclise SDK") Then
    Send("+{TAB}")
  EndIf
EndFunc
```

Once you created the file, just double-click on it and its icon will be in the tray bar, so you can use it whenever you want.