# Java Eclipse CheckStyle Shortcut Key for Apply Checkstyle Fixes

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I used check style in the past and remember using a shortcut key to apply the check style fixes (saves a lot of clicking). I can't remember if I set up a shortcut for it, or if it came with one already.

My question is of two parts:
1) Is there an easy way to check if there is a shortcut key combo for "Apply Checkstyle fixes"?
2) If there isn't one setup, is there a way to set one up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to modify the keyboard shortcuts in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer shortly after posting... here are the steps for documentation purposes:

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Apply Checkstyle fixes (Default: Ctrl+Alt+C)

Comment: I installed checkstyle and pmd but could not find them under keys.  I am using below version of eclipse: Eclipse Platform

Version: Mars (4.5)
Build id: I20150603-2000