# Eclipse Step Debugging Keyboard Keys

Tags: eclipse

How can I customize the keys of the Step Debugger (Java)?

I use different IDEs and each one has its own key layout.  For example, I want to use <kbd>F7</kbd> for step-into instead of the default <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->General->Keys.

You can change the default binding there.