# Why sysout won't work?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-snippets

I checked the preferences settings in my Eclipse, it's all set to default with sysout option on, but when I typed sysout in eclipse, it won't automatically go into `System.out.println()`.
I've checked several other related topics which mention <kbd>ctrl + space</kbd>.
It is a shortcut for input method on my computer. I don't know if this is related to my unable to use the sysout. If not, please let me know how I can get my sysout working.
If yes, please kindly let me know how I can reset 'ctrl + space' or set other shortcut for content assistant.

Comment: type `sysout` and hit `ctrl + space` and it will become `System.out.println();`. This will only work in places were it's legal to write `System.out.println();`, so it won't work directly in the class body, you have to be in a method, constructor or (static) initializer block.

Comment: Are you in the Java perspective? Keyboard shortcuts sometimes change if you're in another perspective. Are you editing a Java source file?

Comment: I think is **syso** and then **ctrl + space**

Comment: @Rollyng: `syso` and `sysout` both work.

Comment: I'm in eclipse modifying a java file. I used it in a method. But whenever I hit ctrl + space, it change to a different input method (eg. Chinese)

Comment: If you accidentally try to put a print statement ouside of a method or code block  using sysout + ctrl + space, then you obviously won't be able to use sysout and you will see this message : Sysout - method stub.

Answer (score 15):

```
Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assistant > Advanced
```

Make sure **Template Proposals** is checked in one of the shown lists.

Comment: This was the source of issues in my case. I disable tons of stuff I don't use in Eclipse and just recently disabled this feature.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I unchecked it, pressed Apply, then checked it again followed by Apply again, now it works for me.

Answer (score 15):

In recent version of Mac (10.14.1) , Mac OS Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts(tab) --> Input sources.

uncheck the setting ctrl +Space.

Now go to Eclipse IDE and it should work.

Comment: In the latest versions like Ventura (MacOS 13), go to the MacOS system settings, then select Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts... -> Input Source -> (Uncheck) Select the previous input source (⌃Space) --> Done. Now go to the Eclipse and try "syso" (or "sysout") and ⌃Space. It will work from now onwards.

Answer (score 10):

You *have to* press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> for the `sysout` (or equivalently: `syso`) shortcut to work in Eclipse, as `sysout` is not part of Java in anyway, on the contrary: it's an abbreviation introduced in Eclipse that only works after you press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> and expands to `System.out.println()`.

By the way, `syserr` (or equivalently: `syse`) will expand to `System.err.println()` after pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>.

Comment: I think my Ctrl + Space is a different function from yours. Whenever I hit ctrl + space, it change to a different input method (eg. Chinese)

Comment: @Zoe looks like a modified Eclipse configuration, the default functionality for Ctrl + Space is autocomplete. Take a look at the keyboard shortcuts and see how's mapped autocomplete, and change it to suit your taste. Look in Eclipse's help, the exact location of the option might have changed between versions and it's better if you refer to your own version's documentation

Answer (score 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

This `public static void` ... blah blah has to be put for the `sysout`
 to work

Comment: I think you mean it has to be inside a valid method.

Answer (score 5):

After trying all the answers above with no success I found another reason why Ctrl+Space could be prevented from working.

In my instance Ctrl+Space worked for some projects in the workspace but not others. I discovered that the project that it did not work for did not have the jdk in the build path, instead it had the jre for the application server (weblogic 12). The application ran fine on the server but Ctrl+Space to open the template proposals didn't work and other things like syntax highlighting were not quite right.

I hope this helps anyone who comes to this questions 3 years after it was asked (Like I did).

Answer (score 3):

```
Eclipse Shortcuts:

Syso + Control + Space:     Puts System.out.println()
Alt + Shift + R:            Rename
Control + F11:              Run
ALT + Up/Down:              move the current line (or lines selected) in the editor up or down 
Control + Shift + O:        Import
Control + I:                Indent
Control + D:                Delete Line
Control + H:                Search Your Entire Project
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem achieving simple ctrl+space templates with eclipse using jre. Showed empty templates for everything.

Try installing the jdk in separate directory then add into Preferences / Installed jre: add in the new directory. Then use that in your build path. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Is there anyway to modify the keyboard shortcuts in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse) here you can find out how to make a custom shortcut `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`

edit: here is a video tutorial http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/how-to-manage-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse/

Comment: I'd like to know how to change ctrl + space to another shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

For me sysout in eclipse created in two lines. println() in new line..Then I found myself  how to avoid this and get System.out.println in one line ..go to Windows > Preferences > Java->Templates (or type templates on search field in top left corner box).Then In template configuring section  uncheck "use code formatter"..thats it.. :)

```
System.out
         .println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you in windows and your keyboard shortcut for eclipse is got replaced with the system keyboard shortcut for language. well, either you replace it the keyboard combination to shows the template proposals by :

```
1. open the preferences dialog
2. go to general -> keys
3. in the search dialog, find the command `Content Assist`
4. change the binding and then click OK button
```

or, you can change the combination key to change the language in the `Text Services and Input Language` and then go to the Advanced Key Settings tab and then change the key sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Select in the menu bar "Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates"
deselect at the lower end of window: "Use code formatter"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work because ctrl+space was being used by another program Ubuntu(I-Bus) in my case ref. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema) Try changing ctrl-space by another key combination in general->keys to find out if this is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same problem with sysout shortcut **when I installed the Scala plug-in** in Enclipse. None of the answers worked, but the solution turned out to be very simple. I **unchecked all Scala templates** in `Preferences -> Scala -> Templates` So if you use any plug-ins, make sure their templates do not get in the way of your Java templates.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. If you use OS X Eclipse Ctrl+Space shortcut can be interfering with OS X system's "*Selecting previous input source*" shortcut using Ctrl+Space shortcut as default. OS X system shortcut has higher priority, that is the reason why Eclipse does not work.

Just go to *System Preferencies/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Input Source* and uncheck the *"Selecting previous input source"* or change the shortcut on something else. Eclipse should work after that even without restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> used as a shortcut for input source in Mac. To disable this go to **settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources** and uncheck Select the previous source. Than syso shortcut will work.

Answer (score 0):

set your perspective on default and your problem will solve.
window -> perspective ->open perspective -> other -> select default

Comment: Why not Java or Java EE perspectives?

Comment: I mean java EE (default).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that today on Java 21 after you define variable as record- the sysout is not resolving normally any more in main body. the sysout resolves before the record definition. So it seems there is something wrong with the record definition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).