# syso shortcut doesn't work in some part of code

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Round15_Ex11 {
    partner in crime
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ②
    }
}
```

---

In Eclipse, `syso` shortcut doesn't work in some part of code.
On the code I posted in the part numbered partner in crime, it doesn't work,
and in the part numbered ②, it works.

And when I write any other class, in the part of class, It works.

What's the matter with shortcut? what am I supposed to fix with?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027355/why-sysout-not-work

Answer (score 1):

That's because you should write it inside a method, like area ②.

It won't compile if you write `System.out.println("Yaay");` [outside a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html), like area ①, so that makes no sense that Eclipse will help you to do something that won't work, otherwise it'll be partner in crime :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work at (1) because you can only **declare** fields and methods in this part. This is why the shortcut won't work. eclipse knows that you cant do that here and will not suggest it. Have a look at [Declaring Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)

You can only call methods like `System.out.println()` in methods (like (2)) or the static block.

(constructors are just "special" methods)