# Having issues with 'sysout' in Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse

I'm having issues with the 'sysout' shortcut in Eclipse IDE. When I type 'sysout' and press ctrl + space, it just opens up the little menu shown in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeljd.png).

If anyone can help me with this issue, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027355/why-sysout-wont-work

Comment: What should it do instead?

Comment: @Abra ur a lifesaver, thank you. All I had to do was turn on 'Insert common prefixes automatically', and that fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

OP here, If anyone else is also having this issue, try going to:

> Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist
>
> Then try turning on `Insert common prefixes automatically`

[image: screen capture of preferences]