# Shortcut keys to show function parameters in Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers?

Tags: php, eclipse

In Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers 3.2.0, is there any shortcut keys that shows the arguments of the function where the cursor is placed?

For example, immediately after I finishing typing the function name and hit enter, there will be a very nice hint tip of what [the parameters of the function](http://postimg.org/image/jqhog4q0t/) are.

However, it easily goes away. What short cut keys should I use to get it back? I remember there's something I could use when the cursor is place inside the [parameters parenthesis](http://postimg.org/image/fimw7dol9/). What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse). Just press `Ctrl + Shift + L` and find the shortcut keys defined as "**Context Information**". That would bring up function parameters when used inside the parameters parenthesis.